# How to remove 'via app' when posting on facebook page feed

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

When posting to the page wall (feed) through my application, under the post contents facebook adds '20 minutes ago *via my_app*'. This is a problem for my company, since they don't want the fans knowing the posting is done through an application, thus losing the personal touch.

Is there any way to lose the '*via my_ap*p' part of the post? These are some of the things I have tried:

- I have given every possible permission on the page admin user, including 'manage_pages'
- Have tried with the token returned from graph api me/accounts for that page / Impersonating pages

Please tell me, short of making a bot to do the whole thing, is there any way to do this through the facebook api.

Thank you for any help you can provide.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Remove "via APP_NAME" on post made from facebook graph api in rails](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/9014659/remove-via-app-name-on-post-made-from-facebook-graph-api-in-rails)

Comment: I have the opposite problem! When posting from my app I don't have the attribute "via my_app" on the post..! I've followed this tutorial: http://www.saaraan.com/2012/02/post-to-facebook-page-wall-using-php-graph Can anyone help?! Thanks

Comment: @AldoB were you able to solve your problem ?

Comment: @AnuradhaJayathilaka no, I'm still trying to solve it.. Are you having the same problem?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want the people to see which company you are, then Facebook is the wrong platform for you!

I'm pretty sure, you also would violate the terms of Facebook (Developer).

Comment: This will only be used for our marketing department, not outsiders or fans. It's my companies Fan Page, of course everyone who visits the page will know who we are. My problem is to use the api to simulate the user typing the post in facebook. The marketing people insist on it, what can I do?

Answer (score 0):

See what your competitors are doing. The largest company in this business has named their app "Publisher". When users click on this a page will open up that doesn't say anything about who created the app - actually it doesn't say anything at all. You could also use the name "Publisher" for your Facebook publishing app - in Facebook app names don't have to be unique.